# how to line up several divs with background images

Tags: css, background-image

I have a very large image to use as a background image. Because the image is so large, I have divided it into three images that can be stacked one on top of the other.

I'm putting the images in as background images with the property "cover":

```
<div class="screen" id="header1"></div>
<div class="screen" id="header2"></div>
<div class="screen" id="header3"></div>
```

css:

```
#header1
{
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1920px;
   max-height: 949px;
   background: url('images/bg1_landscape2.png') no-repeat center center; 
   background-size:cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;

}

#header2
{
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 1920px;
   height: 100%; 
   max-height: 947px;
   background: url('images/bg2_landscape2.png') no-repeat center center; 
   background-size:cover;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;padding: 0;
margin: 0;

}
#header3
{
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
   max-width: 1920px;
   background: url('images/bg3_landscape2.png') no-repeat center center; 
   background-size:cover;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

The problem is that the pattern in the background image doesn't line up.

How do I make multiple background images line up no matter how wide the screen is?

Comment: Could you add a [jdfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I can't show the images--they haven't been made public yet.

Comment: ...if not public, perhaps make up images for an example and repeat the process so we can toy with the code?

Comment: http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/bootstrap/test/test.html

Comment: When you pull the browser window bigger or smaller, sometimes the pattern lines up, sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

So... there's a few things going on here with this:

**1st question :** You haven't done anything to make the div's overlap in your CSS, so they are going to appear just one after the other in the document flow of the browser. For example, view this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/32dzN/):

```
div:first-child {
    background: red;
}
div {
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
div:last-child {
    background: blue;
}
```

If you want them to all overlap perfectly, aka to be superimposed, then they need to be positioned absolutely on top of each other, like this:

```
div:first-child {
    background: red;
}

div {
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

div:last-child {
    background: blue;
}
```

**The other question** is why you would break a large background image into 3 smaller images. We refer to that as image slicing, which is really not optimal. It takes 3 http requests instead of one to retrieve that image, which is more overhead than just getting the smaller one quite often. Also, it's a background image, so it won't prevent the document from fully loading until the image has loaded, as an inline image would.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want them to overlap. I want them to line up regardless of window size. I've broken the background image into three images because the file size is so large.

Comment: Try setting up your bg images so that they are all identical width and height. Currently your heights are different, and you have background-size set to cover, which means your images are going to resize to completely cover the container (no whitespace).

Comment: That does work better, but when I size the browser window wider than 1765px, the image width expands, but not the height, which breaks the pattern.

Comment: If all three of your images are the same width and height now, then by using background size of cover, they should all align and resize the same way. Is this not what you're seeing here?

Comment: Right. Past a certain width, they're not aligning.